# Why does impl overloading work with `for &T where T: MyTrait` but not with `for &dyn MyTrait`?

Tags: rust

Why does this compile:

```rust
trait MyTrait {}

trait MyTraitFrom<'a, T> {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut T) -> Self;
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait> MyTraitFrom<'a, T> for &'a mut T {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut T) -> Self {
        value
    }
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait> MyTraitFrom<'a, &'a mut T> for &'a mut T {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut &'a mut T) -> Self {
        let value: &'a mut T = value;
        value
    }
}
```

but this doesn't:

```rust
trait MyTrait {}

trait MyTraitFrom<'a, T> {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut T) -> Self;
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait> MyTraitFrom<'a, T> for &'a mut dyn MyTrait {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut T) -> Self {
        value
    }
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait> MyTraitFrom<'a, &'a mut T> for &'a mut dyn MyTrait {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut &'a mut T) -> Self {
        let value: &'a mut T = value;
        value
    }
}
```

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `MyTraitFrom<'_, &mut _>` for type `&mut dyn MyTrait`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:1
   |
7  | impl<'a, T: MyTrait> MyTraitFrom<'a, T> for &'a mut dyn MyTrait {
   | --------------------------------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
13 | impl<'a, T: MyTrait> MyTraitFrom<'a, &'a mut T> for &'a mut dyn MyTrait {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `&mut dyn MyTrait`
   |
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `MyTrait` for type `&mut _`
```

Isn't `&'a mut T` more general than `&'a mut dyn MyTrait`?

Comment: Note: `&'a mut &'a mut T` is almost certainly wrong since it [keeps the outer borrow as long as the inner one lives once you use it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=916e3669dd5af59b5bdef0d3c720ae36)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&'a mut T` is indeed more general than `&'a mut dyn MyTrait`...

...if `T` is not constrained somewhere else. Which it is here - the `T` is the same for the generic parameter and the `Self` type.

The more general code, which does not compile either, is:

```rust
impl<'a, T: MyTrait, U> MyTraitFrom<'a, T> for &'a mut U {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut T) -> Self {
        value
    }
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait, U> MyTraitFrom<'a, &'a mut T> for &'a mut U {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut &'a mut T) -> Self {
        let value: &'a mut T = value;
        value
    }
}
```

Think about it: we can list all generic parameters and `Self` to obtain a unique identity for this implementation. If two identities conflict, their `impl`s also do. For the `dyn MyTrait` case, the identities (ignoring lifetimes) are (`&'a mut dyn MyTrait`, `T`) and (`&'a mut dyn MyTrait`, `&'a mut T`). As `&'a mut T` is itself a `T`, this clearly conflicts. The same also applies to the abovementioned example with `U`. However, in your first case, the identitiers are (`&'a mut T`, `T`) and (`&'a mut T`, `&'a mut T`). These do not conflict, as when `T` is `&'a mut T` `&'a mut T` becomes `&'a mut &'a mut T`, and it is not the same as `&'a mut T` anymore.

Comment: Might need a moment to process this :D